# FIR Lattice Filters

Tags: filter, dsp, fir

In DSP, sometimes the so-called Lattice Filters are use, having a structure like on this [picture](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:FIR_Lattice_Filter.png):

[image: Lattice Filter]

I wonder what the advantages of the Lattice structure are, compared to other FIR filter types and what the applications of Lattice filters are.

Comment: shameless advertising: this would fit *greatly* on http://signals.stackexchange.com, the sister site for signal processing.

Comment: also, there's something off about the specific shape this picture shows. The last summer in the lower row is superfluous if you don't plan to output that internal state.

Comment: What you have here is an **unrolled loop**. You can feed the output of each stage into the very same function again and again, only changing k. Try rolling this up into a loop. See how simple your program becomes.

Comment: so the only advantage of the Lattice filter is the possibility of using a unrolled loop?